# Memory-efficient lookup table of DataFrames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray, h5py

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70523263/design-pattern-for-filtering-by-attributes) I asked, a responder suggested I organize my data as a DataFrame of DataFrames.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Form': {0:'SUV', 1:'Truck', 2:'SUV', 3:'Sedan', 4:'SUV', 5:'Truck'},
                   'Make': {0:'Ford', 1:'Toyota', 2:'Honda', 3:'Ford', 4:'Honda', 5:'Toyota'},
                   'Color': {0:'White', 1:'Black', 2:'Gray', 3:'White', 4:'White', 5:'Black'},
                   'Driver age': {0:25, 1:37, 2:21, 3:54, 4:50, 5:67},
                   'Data': {0: pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [0.25, 1.7], [1.2, 1.8], [4.5, 4.0]]), 
                            1: pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [0.15, 1.3], [1.6, 1.3], [4.2, 4.1]]), 
                            2: pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [0.24, 1.2], [1.3, 1.6], [4.1, 3.9]]), 
                            3: pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [0.45, 1.6], [1.8, 1.8], [4.2, 4.6]]), 
                            4: pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [0.85, 1.9], [1.5, 1.7], [4.5, 4.3]]), 
                            5: pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [0.35, 1.8], [1.5, 1.8], [4.6, 4.1]])} })
```

This DataFrame of DataFrames permits me to conditionally select groups of data e.g. `df[(df['make'] == 'SUV') and (df['age']<=40)]['Data']`. The trouble is when each row of data is itself a large `.csv`, it becomes hard to load into memory.

I'm looking for a module like `h5py` that can "stream"/read in specific portions of data (which permits specifying a key e.g. `df = pd.read_hdf('large_data.hdf', 'SUV-Ford-White-25')`, except **rather than a nested dictionary** I would prefer it be a **table** that permits filtering e.g. `df = module.read(large_data.some_ext, make == 'SUV', 20 <= age <= 40)`. Does `xarray` or `pandas` have something built in for this?

Comment: if you have access to a shell, you can pre filter there with `subprocess.run` or `janitor.io.read_commandline` before loading into pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `h5py`, PyTables (aka `tables`) can also create and read HDF5 files. Pandas
uses PyTables "under the hood" to create and read HDF5 files. PyTables has some useful search features to do exactly what you want to do. For completeness, I included a brief summary at the end of this answer that compares each package.

Here is an example I created to demonstrate the search behavior using your dataframe (dictionary) data.

**To create the HDF5 file**:
Note: most of the "work" creating the HDF5 file is (re)organizing your dictionary data into a NumPy recarray. The process can be simplified if the data structure is modified (shifting dictionary key/value levels) -- that assumes the structure isn't set yet.
Summary of steps:

1. Create a `np.dtype` that defines the fields (columns) of data.
2. Determine recarray rows by counting the number of dictionary items associated to each primary key.
3. Create a recarray of zeros with 1 and 2 above.
4. Loop thru the dictionary and map keys and values to appropriate row and field(column) name.

**Code below**:

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

data_dict = {'Form': {0:'SUV', 1:'Truck', 2:'SUV', 3:'Sedan', 4:'SUV', 5:'Truck'},
                   'Make': {0:'Ford', 1:'Toyota', 2:'Honda', 3:'Ford', 4:'Honda', 5:'Toyota'},
                   'Color': {0:'White', 1:'Black', 2:'Gray', 3:'White', 4:'White', 5:'Black'},
                   'Driver_age': {0:25, 1:37, 2:21, 3:54, 4:50, 5:67},
                   'Data': {0: np.array([[0, 0], [0.25, 1.7], [1.2, 1.8], [4.5, 4.0]]), 
                            1: np.array([[0, 0], [0.15, 1.3], [1.6, 1.3], [4.2, 4.1]]), 
                            2: np.array([[0, 0], [0.24, 1.2], [1.3, 1.6], [4.1, 3.9]]), 
                            3: np.array([[0, 0], [0.45, 1.6], [1.8, 1.8], [4.2, 4.6]]), 
                            4: np.array([[0, 0], [0.85, 1.9], [1.5, 1.7], [4.5, 4.3]]), 
                            5: np.array([[0, 0], [0.35, 1.8], [1.5, 1.8], [4.6, 4.1]])} }

recarr_dt = np.dtype( [ ('Form','S10'), ('Make','S10') , ('Color','S10'),
                        ('Driver_age',int), ('Data',float, (4,2)) ] )
nrows = 0
for k, d in data_dict.items():
    nrows = max(nrows, len(d))

recarr = np.zeros(shape=(nrows,), dtype=recarr_dt)  

for k1, v1 in data_dict.items():
    for k2, v2 in  v1.items():
        recarr[k2][k1] = v2
        
with tb.File('SO_71388372.h5','w') as h5w:
    h5w.create_table('/', 'test', obj=recarr)
```

**To open and search the HDF5 file**:
This example demonstrates 2 searches using the `Table.read_where(condition)` method. It shows the syntax for multiple search conditions. Some things to watch for:

1. Parenthesis required for multiple conditions
2. No compound conditions (`20 <= Driver_age <= 40`) is 2 conditions
3. Strings are entered as `b"text"` (b/c HDF5 strings aren't Unicode).

**Code below**:

```
import tables as tb
with tb.File('SO_71388372.h5','r') as h5r:
    data_tbl = h5r.root.test
    
    condition = '(Form == b"SUV") & (20 <= Driver_age) & (Driver_age <= 40)'
    data_arr = data_tbl.read_where(condition)
    print(f'\nFor search condition: {condition}')
    print(f'# of rows found: {data_arr.shape}')
    for row in data_arr:
        print(row)
        
    condition = '(Form == b"SUV") & (Make == b"Honda")'
    data_arr = data_tbl.read_where(condition)
    print(f'\nFor search condition: {condition}')
    print(f'# of rows found: {data_arr.shape}')
    for row in data_arr:
        print(row)
```

Here is summary of each package extracted from their respective FAQ pages.

**PyTables (from PyTables FAQ)**:
Builds an additional abstraction layer on top of HDF5 and NumPy. Has an engine to enable complex queries, an efficient computational kernel, and advanced indexing capabilities. Has a custom system to represent data types available in the HDF5 library but not in NumPy.

**h5py (from h5py FAQ)**:
Attempts to map the HDF5 feature set to NumPy as closely as possible. Also provides access to nearly all of the HDF5 C API. The high-level type system uses NumPy dtype objects exclusively, and method and attribute naming follows Python and NumPy conventions for dictionary and array access.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for!!!

Comment: @batlike, the most complicated step above is mapping data from the dictionary of dictionaries (since the 1st key is field name and the 2nd key is the row data). How do you import your data and create the dictionaries? If you import data from CSV files, this can be simplified using `np.genfromtxt()`. Also, I created a (4,2) array for `'Data'` based on your example. This needs to be sized for the largest vehicle trajectory dataset you expect to save. Design of the HDF5 schema is critical - more important than the code. Coding is easy with a good schema. :-)